# d3 - Is there any possibilities of adding brush event to difference chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[**This**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3894205) is the chart I'm trying out.

I want to add the `brush` event and zoom-in and zoom-out like we have in [**this**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) chart.

Here's the [**code**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LjGR/5/) which I'm still trying to plot a brush event.

This is the first time I'm doing this referring to this [**site**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls).

Any help will be very much useful for me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

I almost managed to do it.

Now I have some problem with the line.

When you filter the chart in the fiddle you can see it.

Above and below classes are fixed and it's not getting changed on the brush event.

Someone help me out?

Comment: Check the fiddle in the response. I think it is doing what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8rVdv/). And here is the key code piece:

```
function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent()); 
    focus.select("#clip-below>path").attr("d", area.y0(height));
    focus.select("#clip-above>path").attr("d", area.y0(0));
    focus.select(".area.above").attr("d", area.y0(function(d) { return y(d["San Francisco"]); }));
    focus.select(".area.below").attr("d", area);    
    focus.select("path.line").attr("d", line(data));
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Believe it or not. I managed to figure that out and it's working exactly the same you've given in the fiddle. One more thing I've got i this is that when we brush it's zooming in beyond the start of y axis. I didn't figure out why it's like that and I'm still scratching my head on it. Can you help me out?

Comment: Excellent, great minds think alike? :) But yes, indeed, I did see the issue with the axis and made a mental note to revisit  it later when I have some time...but who knows, you may beat me to it?!

Comment: :). I'm already scratching over it. Try to help me out when you get some time.

Comment: We hit a barrier with the adaptation...to see what I mean, add `clip-path: url(#clip);` to the css for `.line`. Run the fiddle...nice. Now do the same for `.area.above` and `area.below`. Run the fiddle and you will hit the issue. If you inspect the elements, you will see that one of the areas is apparently overlaying the other.

Comment: Yes it is. Any idea how to overcome it?